# Добавление контекстного меню к TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Как к TreeView добавить контекстное меню с удаление выбранного элемента?

Получили treeViewItem. Как теперь его удалить?

```
<TreeView x:Name="tw_tree"   TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded" MinWidth="200"  TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItem_SelectedItem" Background="#FF222222" 
PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="tv_dep_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown">               

                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=collection_node}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="30"
                                Source="{Binding level, Converter={StaticResource LevelToImageConverter}}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}" >
                                <TextBlock.ContextMenu >
                                <ContextMenu>Delete</ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>


private void tv_dep_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch<TreeViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as TreeViewItem;

            if (treeViewItem != null)
            {
                treeViewItem.Focus();
            }
        }

        static DependencyObject VisualUpwardSearch<T>(DependencyObject source)
        {
            while (source != null && source.GetType() != typeof(T))
                source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

            return source;
        }
```

Почему удаляются сразу все подветки? Выбрана только одна.

```
TreeViewItem treeViewItem = VisualUpwardSearch<TreeViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as TreeViewItem;

            if (treeViewItem != null)
            {
                treeViewItem.Focus();
                ItemsControl parent = GetSelectedTreeViewItemParent(treeViewItem);
                parent.ItemsSource = null;

                parent.Items.Remove(treeViewItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай команду на удаление элемента. В MenuItem, св-во Command задай созданную команду, а в CommandParameter привяжи свойство SelectedItem из TreeView